# VB.net Simple IRC Client

Tags: .net, vb.net, client, irc

How would I go about making a simple IRC client with these things

What I am using:

```
Nickname TextBox
Connect Button
Message TextBox
Send Message Button
Refresh Button
ListBox
```

Restrictions:

```
No commands at all just being able to send messages
```

I am using a listbox for recieving messages

Comment: It'll be impossible without a box for specifying the server and channel.

Comment: How would it be impossible? You can preset the server and channel.

Comment: Yeah mathepic, you didn't quite think that comment out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a client connection to create a raw connection to the IRC server, however, you will need to read up on the IRC protocol. Take a look at the links below:

- [MSDN: Client Connection
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a.aspx)
- [IRC Protocol:
  http://irchelp.org/irchelp/rfc/rfc.html](http://irchelp.org/irchelp/rfc/rfc.html)

Comment: Thanks, I have already figured out how to make the client. Currently trying to make my ListBox autoscroll any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Read the RFC listed above and then use the sockets component.